# Install part of a bower/npm dependency. Like bootstrap grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, bower

Is there a way to install part of a dependency, like only bootstrap-grid instead of the whole bootstrap(as provided in the customizable downloads of bootstrap), using npm or bower? or any other dependency package manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can't install "only part of a dependency", whatever the package manager. Though, when you reach this case, this "part of a dependency" is probably available as a dependency itself, like the example you told : `bootstrap-grid`

`npm install bootstrap-grid`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-grid